# Upgraded to El Capitan, now getting "The requested URL was not found on this server" error on my localhost project

Tags: python, macos, apache, server, localhost

[image]

Upgraded to [El Capitan](http://www.apple.com/osx/?cid=wwa-us-kwg-mac) and now getting **"The requested URL was not found on this server"** error, this use to work fine in Mavericks and Yosemite.

My Python version `2.7.10`

Here is my Apache log:

```
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2469] AH00163: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
[core:notice] [pid 2469] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd'
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2469] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 77] AH00163: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
[core:notice] [pid 77] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 77] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2196] AH00163: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
[core:notice] [pid 2196] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

---

**UPDATE**

Another dev told me the problem is we can't install `mod_wsgi` or move files into my `/usr/libexec/apache2` folder.

So my `httpd` won't run, no idea why that is, because I am the root.

Trying to figure out why that is atm...

---

Is there anything else you would need to see? I'm at a lost as to what is going on.

Viewing just `localhost` I do get the "It works" message:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the issue:** [Reinstall ModWSGI after upgrading to ElCapitan](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/98)

Had to install ModWSGI
https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases

My config for project was actually in the `wsgi.conf` file

Some edits where made in that and it was imported into my `httpd.conf` file:

`Include /private/etc/apache2/wsgi.conf`

After stopping and restarting Apache, finally back up!

The other dev did some sysadmin wizardry, I tried to capture it all above.